# Is there a way to get key of a dictionary entry from its value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a small program to filter out all negative values in a dictionary, using a lambda function. I have to again write it as a dictionary, with no negative values. It seems index() function is not supported in 3.x standard. Any pointers to how to go about writing this code would be helpful.

```
a = {'a':1,'b':-5,'c':-4,'d':-8,'e':9}
key = a.keys()
val = a.values()
l1 = list(filter(lambda x:x>0,val))
print(l1)
```

One more constraint is: I have to use a lambda function. So, using comprehension as said in the answer won't be allowed. I have seen the question of which this may be a duplicate: but sampling one of the answers in there, I tried

```
    dict(filter(lambda x,y:y>=0,a.items()))
```

I got this: TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'y

Comment: In 3.6+ dictionaries are ordered by insertion; in previous versions you are encouraged to use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you're trying to filter a dict, creating a list of *only values without keys* is just counterproductive.

Comment: @cuperto please consider using 'key' instead of 'index' in the question title since dictionaries do not have indexes, but keys.

Comment: @fabianegli Hi, I have edited my question as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Use `dict` comprehension:

```
{k:v for k,v in a.items() if v>0}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'e': 9}
```